# Java Code Works in App, not in Servlet

Tags: java, macos, servlets, netbeans, noclassdeffounderror

Here's the situation.

I'm implementing facial recognition software on a Java Web Application, which includes two .jar files and a .dylib native library. In a normal java application, the code works fine, however when I try to load the library in a servlet, I'm getting the error that the .dylib can't be found. How can I get the servlet to load the library so that I can access the facial recognition software?

Here's my code. The Java App that works.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    FSDK.ActivateLibrary("G2TfLOGUH8hQehjxiB...");
    FSDK.Initialize();
    FSDK.Finalize();
}
```

Here's the servlet.

```
@WebServlet(name = "glassesServlet", urlPatterns = {"/glassesServlet"})
public class glassesServlet extends HttpServlet {

/** 
 * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code> methods.
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    try {

    FSDK.ActivateLibrary("G2TfLOGUH8hQehjxiBZtJvjmwyu...");
    FSDK.Initialize();
    FSDK.Finalize();

    } finally {            
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Now, here's the error that the server gives each time I try to run from the server.

```
WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[glassesServlet]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet         
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class Luxand.FSDK$IFaceSDK
```

plus some other code that details where it originated. That class, `Luxand.FSDK$IFaceSDK` is a class inside the .jar file that is stored in the Library folder.

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: If this were Linux I'd say you'd want to make sure that the native library is in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH of the servlet container

Comment: and on windows, may be inside system32 folder. btw, when it works on the app, is it because its in the classpath? if yes, have you tried putting the library in WEB-INF/lib ?

Answer (score 2):

make sure the library folder is on classpath of deployment environment

Answer (score 0):

Both of the above answers are right. To give a little more detail...

On your laptop it's probably just picking up the .dylib file from the root of your project.

On Linux, you need the .so file. It doesn't matter where it is as long as it is on the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable path. I've found the easiest way is to set that on the command-line launching the server.

So if you're using a fat JAR, it would be something like:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/luxand/luxand-something.so java -jar Server.jar -Dsomeothersetting=something
```